# Creating a FAT(16) partition at maximum size on a flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, fat16

Got a copy of AR MAX for use with now very antiquated PS2, but it doesn't recognize my flash drive because it isn't FAT format apparently. It's a 32 gb drive and there's no option to format it to FAT. I could go the route of purchasing a 1gb flash drive that is formatted to FAT, or as far as I've looked around for hours I might be able to make a partition with DISKPART. I'm really confused about how to size my partition (the "size" value) and my head is exploding at trying to find help through a web search.

Can this really be done by partitioning?

FAT can have a max volume of about 2 gb, so what's a safe maximum to size my partition via DISKPART? What number should I input? I might have to go lower than 1 gb, I've read conflicting information on AR MAX, some say it may not work with a drive over a gigabyte but another has reported it working with a 16 gb Sandisk Cruz. Someone here at SuperUser noted that FAT cannot be given a size of 512mb, but I am perplexed at what this even means. Even if someone convinces me to buy a 1 gb drive, it would still be cool to have this information for reference.

Anyway you look at it, it's a waste of money to have a drive that works with AR MAX. So worth it though.

Comment: I don't do Windows, so I cant answer the specifics, but yes, you should be able to partition a USB Disk of any large-enough size (using FDISK or DISKPART) - you should be able to give the partition whatever size you want up to the maximum size of a FAT16 partition - which is 2 gigs.   You need to ensure the correct of 0x04 (or partition type of FAT16).   You then need to format the disk using the FAT16 file system.

Comment: Partitioning the drive worked like a charm. Unfortunately I think I may have gotten the wrong disc for my PS2. I even tried a USB stick I had around the house (no purchase necessary) and it didn't work either. Anyway, thanks for the valuable information. I'll probably keep learning about this stuff as it is incredibly useful. I'm glad I could use a flash drive as a dummy.